# SUBSTR in sql oracle from right

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data in table 000_ABC_AXEL. The expectation is that i have to exclude data after the last '_' and get 000_ABC in oracle sql? Any suggestions?

Need sql query to achieve below
for ex:

```
a_222_4 -- > expected result :a_222
123_xyz_0 -- >expected result :123_xyz
```

Answer (score 3):

A regex replacement fits your requirement nicely:

```sql
SELECT col, REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '_[^_]+$', '') AS col_out
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with simple string functions (which are much faster than regular expressions) by finding the sub-string up to the character before the last underscore:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(col, 1, INSTR(col, '_', -1) - 1) AS first_parts
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (col) AS
SELECT 'a_222_4'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123_xyz_0' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| FIRST_PARTS |
| --- |
| a_222 |
| 123_xyz |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/igZcOtjF)